# Split field values using specific character

Tags: php, sql, oracle

Please help me with this.

It is possible to split field values using a specific character? Here is my sample table

```
value
10uF
2K
1.0uF
200UF
```

I want it to split by this:

```
value       capacitance/resistance
 10            uF
 2             K
 1.0           uF
 200           UF
```

PS: I am using Oracle and the numbers should be separated from letters

Answer (score 0):

Use split

```
array split ( string $pattern , string $string [, int $limit = -1 ] )


 <?php
  // Delimiters may be slash, dot, or hyphen
  $date = "04/30/1973";
  list($month, $day, $year) = split('[/.-]', $date);
  echo "Month: $month; Day: $day; Year: $year<br />\n";
?>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer but can I have sql query instead?

Comment: For SQL statement you ca use `INSTR`

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions:

```
with src as 
(select '10uF' as val from dual
union all
select '2K' from dual
union all
select '1.0uF' from dual
union all 
select '200UF' from dual)
select 
   regexp_substr(val,'[[:digit:]]+[\.]*[[:digit:]]*',1) as val
  ,regexp_substr(val,'[[:alpha:]]+',1) as resistance  
from src
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my try, with regex:

```
SELECT 
  val, regexp_substr(val,'[[:digit:]|.]*') num,
  substr(val,regexp_instr(val,'[^[:digit:]|^\.]')) chars
FROM (
      select '10uF' as val from dual union all
      select '2K' from dual union all 
      select '1.0uF' from dual union all
      select '200UF' from dual
);
```

First expression takes first match of digits and dots as many as they are.
The second substring value for what is after first expression(it negates it).